# Is there a way to make the Facebook PHP SDK and Javascript SDK communicate

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-graph-api

I use the PHP SDK for several backend functions that integrate Facebook, and I use the Javascript SDK to do things like embed widgets (eg: Like buttons etc).

Is there a technique to get them to communicate with each other? Eg, if my users login using my sites social login (which uses the PHP SDK) can I log that info with the JS stuff allowing them to interact with the Graph API.

Perhaps there is a way of including the users token in the JS embed code so that it is aware?

I can't seem to find anything that discusses this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the JS SDK to login you can configure it to create the facebook cookie. You can then extract the token from that and use it in the PHP sdk, as covered [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)

```
FB.init({appId: 'your app id', status: true, cookie: true,
             xfbml: true});
```

If you set `cookie` to true, you'll get a cookie on the server side with a token you can pass into the PHP sdk.

Comment: It is actually the other way I am more interested in. I store users tokens in the database so I was wondering if there is a way to initialise the JS SDK stuff with a token so a JS Login is not required.

Comment: Ah: well, not really. What you can do is pass the token to the page and then use JSONP on the graph API by using (for example) `getJSON` in jquery and specifying a callback function as shown at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669781/howto-get-jsonp-and-facebook-graph-api-to-work.

Answer (score 2):

As of now (August 2011), Facebook has upgraded their PHP and JS sdks to fully support OAuth 2.0.  See https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/ and http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/534/.

Before the OAuth 2.0 migration, you could use a `session` option to the `FB.init` method to pass in a user session to the js sdk.  That technically still works although it is being phased out (October 1, 2011 is the OAuth 2.0 migration deadline).

If you set `cookie` and `oauth` to true in the `FB.init` js call, it will look for a cookie named `fbsr_APPID` (where APPID is your application's app id).  That cookie needs to contain the [signed request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/).

I haven't found sample code on how to construct the signed request in PHP, but it should be possible to reverse the code sample Facebook provides for decoding the signed request.

To summarize:

1. Create a signed request from the user credentials.
2. Set that to the `fbsr_APPID` cookie
3. Load the JS SDK with `cookie` and `oauth` set to true in `FB.init`