# Making Facebook's Graph API with tokens work in Internet Explorer

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, facebook-graph-api

I've encountered several issues while trying to get Facebook's Graph API work in IE.

The first problem was that I was getting a `No Transport` when making a call to `https://graph.facebook.com`. The issue here is XDomainRequest and was eventually solved by using this workaround: https://github.com/jaubourg/ajaxHooks/blob/master/src/ajax/xdr.js (I'm using jQuery and XDomainRequest is [not supported](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8283))

Now the problem that I have is that I'm getting "Access is Denied" while making calls to `https://graphs.facebook.com`.  After some reading, I found out from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx) that:

> 7) Requests must be targeted to the same scheme as the hosting page

And of course, I was making calls from `http` (my domain) to `https` (graphs.facebook), and that goes against the aforementioned point #7.

So what I first tried was to make a call to `http://graphs.facebook.com` instead, and that works...but only when not using an `access_token` in your request; and I need to include my token in all the requests.

So, apart from buying a certificate and putting my site on `https` (which I won't do), what can I do to make successful ajax calls to a domain which uses a different scheme in IE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your AJAX call must be a JSONP type, not a JSON type.  The P in JSONP is the way to get around the issue with IE.  See an example here for calling with JSONP to facebook. [How to query the Facebook Graph API with JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669781/howto-get-jsonp-and-facebook-graph-api-to-work)

Comment: Excellent!  Adding `callback=?` to my queries fixed the issue.