# Javascript, AJAX & PHP working in Chrome but not in Firefox, Safari, IE

Tags: javascript, php, sql, pdo, cross-browser

**UPDATE:**

I've found out what's been causing this problem. The webpage has a piece of Javascript contained inside its body which is preventing the Javascript `body onload=` function from executing in Firefox, Safari and IE. Chrome is able to run both without problems. To solve this I've tried moving the script inside `<head>..</head>` however that script will not work for me there, it seems like it needs to be inside the body (I've tried calling it from an external .js file too but it won't work from there either). This is the body onload function along with the problematic script:

```
<html>
<head>
//some Javascript & Style files are included here..
</head>
    <body onload="getUserDetails()">

    <script>
    window.onload = function() {
        $('#selectAllFriends').change(function(){
                if (this.checked) {
                    $('#mfsForm :checkbox').each(function() {
                        this.checked = true;
                    })
                }
                else {
                    $('#mfsForm :checkbox').each(function() {
                        this.checked = false;
                    })
                }
            });
    }
    </script>

    //rest of page body is contained here...

    </body>
</html>
```

This script is needed as part of a Facebook Multi-Friend Selector. I think maybe the problem is to do with running `window.onload` and `body onload=` at the same time? Is there a way to maybe delay the Multi-Friend Selector script for a couple of seconds to let the `body onload=` function to run first, and would that resolve the problem?

**Original Question:**

I have a Javascript function which gets called on page load. Inside this function there’s a call to Facebook’s Graph API, this call gets user details from Facebook, and then passes them by an AJAX post to a PHP script.

**This is the Javascript I'm using:**

```
function getUserDetails() {

FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');

     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
     if (response.error) {
       console.log('Error - ' + response.error.message);
     }
     else {
       var userid = response.id;
       var userfirst_name = response.first_name;
       var userlast_name = response.last_name;
       var useremail = response.email;
       var usergender = response.gender;

       $.ajax({
         url: 'insertdetails.php',
         data: {'userid' : userid,
               'userfirst_name' : userfirst_name,
               'userlast_name' : userlast_name,
               'useremail' : useremail,
               'usergender' : usergender},
        type: "POST",
        success: function(response){

                 if(response==1){
                         alert( "Insert Successful!");
                         }
                    else{
                       alert( "Insert Failed!" );
                              }
                    }
       });
     }
    });
  } else {
    console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
  }
 }, {scope: 'email'});
}
```

Originally the PHP script contained two basic Insert statements which inserted these details into two tables in my database. This worked perfectly, but it wasn’t secure, so yesterday I wrote a PDO prepared transaction statement instead. I later found out that my database engine (MyISAM) doesn’t support PDO transaction statements, so I decided instead to run two queries (that would insert data into the two tables) inside the same PHP script instead (I know this isn’t best practice but I couldn’t find a way to get PDO transactions to work with MyISAM).

This is the part that’s confusing to me: when testing the new PHP file, I find that it works perfectly when I open the page in Chrome, however it doesn’t work with Firefox, IE, or Safari.

**The PHP script**

```
<?php
$servername = "myserver";
$username = "myusername";
$password = "mypassword";
$dbname = "mydatabase";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // prepare sql and bind parameters for 1st insert
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user (fb_id, f_name, l_name, email, gender) 
    VALUES (:fb_id, :firstname, :lastname, :email, :gender)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':fb_id', $userid);
    $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $userfirst_name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $userlast_name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $useremail);
    $stmt->bindParam(':gender', $usergender);

    // insert a row
    $userid = $_POST['userid'];
    $userfirst_name = $_POST['userfirst_name'];
    $userlast_name = $_POST['userlast_name'];
    $useremail = $_POST['useremail'];
    $usergender = $_POST['usergender'];
    $stmt->execute();

    // prepare sql and bind parameters for 2nd insert
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO orders (fb_id, cb, gb, invite) 
    VALUES (:fb_id, :cb, :gb, :invite)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':fb_id', $userid);
    $stmt->bindParam(':cb', $cb);
    $stmt->bindParam(':gb', $gb);
    $stmt->bindParam(':invite', $inviteo);

    // insert a row
    $userid = $_POST['userid'];
    $cb = "1";
    $gb = "10";
    $inviteo = "0";
    $stmt->execute();

    echo "1";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
$conn = null;
?>
```

Once the insert statements are completed I send an echo back to the Javascript function, and then a Javascript alert appears on screen to tell me if the insert was successful or not. This works perfectly in Chrome, but I don’t get any alert with the other three browsers, and nothing gets entered into the database when I try to use them. The fact that there’s no alert telling me it’s not successful makes me think that the error is in the Javascript not working with the browsers, but then again, it was working perfectly on all browsers before I switched the PHP to PDO.

I've made sure that Javascript is enabled, pop-ups aren't blocked, and I've tried looking at the console in Firefox but I don't see what could be wrong.

Any help or advice on this would be great. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to trace precisely where the error comes from (server side ? client side ? is the data well encoded ? etc) ?

Comment: this is one of the issues that may occure : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8995544/4884034 but @Heru-Luin is right we need more informations to help you (I know that apps with an API call are tricky to debug because you have to know where the bug comes from first)

Comment: Hi @Heru-Luin and Daniel thanks for your replies, I've just tried using JSNOP but it's still giving the same result. I'm very confused because it was working on all browers before I started to use PDO, so is the problem with my SQL/PHP script? maybe there's something in the SQL syntax that's making it incompatible with the other browsers? What would be the best way to trace where the error comes from, what steps should I take to do this? Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @Daniel I wasn't able to tag you in the above comment, so I'm tagging you here :)

Comment: @Emily you should try to see what's going on with the ajax requests first to see if it's returning what you want, you can check it by opening your website, then use CTRL+MAJ+i , go on the "Network" section and launch your ajax by refreshing your website (F5) you can check what exactly is returned by your query

Comment: Hi @Daniel I've opened the Network section and navigated to the ui.js file (that's the file that contains the function), under "response" it just gives me the code of the function. However after looking more I found a list containing my name, Facebook ID, photo etc, all the details in my Graph API request. But I'm unable to find the AJAX response using Firefox's console, would the fact that everything works on all browsers when the SQL is a normal insert statement mean that the PDO code isn't compatible with Firefox, Safari and IE? Is there anything else that I can try? Thanks again!

Comment: You have to see the response for your request  in the Network section, even if it's an error it will still display something. I think you're not looking for the right thing, it's hard to explain to you how you should be able to see the request ^^'

Comment: PDO does not influence browser compatibility, it is only used server side.
However, if you do not handle it correctly server-side, it can lead to unexpected answer of the request.
Have you tried to `console.log` or `alert` the result of your request ?

Comment: Hi @Daniel I'm still unable to find the response for the request, but I ran the php script directly in the browser to see it's response (it should be "1" if successful), instead it gave me this error message: ``Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out``

Comment: Hi again @Daniel I've figured out what the problem is, I have a script running on the html page which is interfering with the ``body onload=`` function which contains the AJAX post to the php file. I've updated my question with the new data, if you could take a look at it that would be awesome! Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @Heru-Luin it turns out the problem is being caused by another script running on the page, I've updated my question with more data on this, I'd appreciate any advice you might have on it, thank you.