# exact string to getJSON and callback=?

Tags: jquery, facebook, jsonp

I'm trying to make getJSON to use JSONP object, but I can't figure out how to build the url:

for instance: http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://legrandj.eu/article/blouse_ghost_dream

where and how should I add "callback=?" parameter?

thank you

d.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669781/howto-get-jsonp-and-facebook-graph-api-to-work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Append `&callback=?` to the URL.

```
$.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://legrandj.eu/article/blouse_ghost_dream&callback=?', function(data) {
    // ..
});
// Or (more clean): 
$.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/?callback=?',
    {
        ids: 'http://legrandj.eu/article/blouse_ghost_dream'
    },
    function(data) {
        // ...
    }
);
```

Given this code, jQuery creates and inserts a `<script src="http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://legrandj.eu/article/blouse_ghost_dream&callback=jQuery171022388557461090386_1332329918803&_=133232991983">`. Explanation of the URL:

- Base URL: http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://legrandj.eu/article/blouse_ghost_dream
- Callback handler: `&callback=jQuery171022388557461090386_1332329918803`
  **jQuery replaces `?` in `callback=?` with an unique temporary identifier**.
- Cache-breaking: `&_=133232991983`

The FB API returns a response in the following format ([JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)):

```
/**/ jQuery171022388557461090386_1332329918803({
   "http://legrandj.eu/article/blouse_ghost_dream": {
      "id": "http://legrandj.eu/article/blouse_ghost_dream",
      "shares": 3
   }
});
```

Since this is included by the `<script>` tag, a function `jQuery171022388557461090386_1332329918803` is called, passing the parsed JSON as an argument. The parsed JSON is then passed to the function which you defined in `jQuery.getJSON`.

Comment: no way, try it yourself: "http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://legrandj.eu/article/blouse_ghost_dream&callback=?"

Comment: @Daniele I have tried it, it does work. Example of result: [`http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://legrandj.eu/article/blouse_ghost_dream&callback=test`](http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://legrandj.eu/article/blouse_ghost_dream&callback=test)

Comment: this works fine and returns the right object http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://legrandj.eu/article/blouse_ghost_dream

Comment: @Daniele jQuery replaces the `?` in `callback=?` with a temporary function, like `jQuery123465789646`. Do you understand how jQuery.getJSON works with JSONP?

Comment: with the question mark at the end I have no results. Jquery docs are not clear about this: "If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by the server-side API)". Do you think jquery will treat this as jsonp even without question mark?