# jsonp thru jQuery.getJSON not working in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery, jsonp

This works in Chrome and Firefox, but a call to .getJSON with "?jsoncallback?" suffix to the url fails with a 'No Transport' error in IE.

Any experience with this around whether this does or does not work, will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer seems to have a more strict cross domain policy preventing use without the callback being set correctly.

The cross domain calls will work if you replace ?jsoncallback? with ?callback=?

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9803766/1254222