# ajax call works in Chrome, Firefox but not in IE?

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, facebook-graph-api

The following code works fine in Chrome, Firefox and Komodo Dragon.  I'ts even a clean install of firefox (proving I'm not authenticated to FB or anything). It does not work in IE.  Chrome, FF and dragon all result in an alert with a valid access_token.  IE results in "Access Denied". I've tried GET and POST, both have same results.

```
    function getWallPosts() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=<facebookid>&client_secret=<secretcode>&grant_type=client_credentials',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data)
            },
            error: function (a, b, c) {
                alert(a + ' ' + b + ' ' + c);
            }
        });
    };
```

**EDIT: Additional Information***

I tried using XDomainRequest as recommended in the comments, however I still receive Access Denied in IE only.  I believe this is the reason why:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx

> Requests must be targeted to the same scheme as the hosting page
>
> This restriction means that if your AJAX page is at
>   http://example.com, then your target URL must also begin with HTTP.
>   Similarly, if your AJAX page is at https://example.com, then your
>   target URL must also begin with HTTPS.
>
> It was definitely our intent to prevent HTTPS pages from making
>   XDomainRequests for HTTP-based resources, as that scenario presents a
>   Mixed Content Security Threat which many developers and most users do
>   not understand.
>
> However, this restriction is overly broad, because it prevents HTTP
>   pages from issuing XDomainRequests targeted to HTTPS pages. While it’s
>   true that the HTTP page itself may have been compromised, there’s no
>   reason that it should be forbidden from receiving public resources
>   securely.
>
> Worst of all, the Same Scheme restriction means that web developers
>   testing their pages locally using the file:// scheme will find that
>   all of the XDomainRequests are blocked because file:// doesn’t match
>   either http:// or https://, which are the only valid target schemes
>   (point #1). To workaround this issue, web developers must host their
>   pages on a local web server (e.g. IIS, the Visual Studio hosting
>   server, etc).
>
> To workaround this limitation, you can build a
>   postMessage-Proxy-for-XDR.

The hosting package I have been provided does not include any SSL options.  Does anyone else have any other ideas?

Comment: I think this is probably your issue, now that I'm looking more closely:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087549/access-denied-to-jquery-script-on-ie

Comment: That still didn't work, I'll update my question with the reason.

Comment: Have you looked at JSONP?  It's beyond my realm of experience, but this looks like another possibility: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669781/howto-get-jsonp-and-facebook-graph-api-to-work

Comment: That's what I'm exploring now but I'm not having much luck so far.  May have a question incoming related to that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was making the ajax call to a server-side service, then having that service make the OAuth call.  In my case, I used an asp.net ASMX service.  It could also be PHP or anything.  This is now working.